# google map auto filling is not working in android webview

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, android-webview

i'm using webview concept in android. in web page i'm using a address auto fill. it is working in browser , but when i make that website into webview that auto filling is not working .

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
   myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
   myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
   myWebView.loadUrl("www.vacationgod.com/taxi");
```

this is mainactivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in your code!

```
myWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
myWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebview.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884" + "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355");
```